# Creating a 2D matrix in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created a 2D matrix in two different ways in JavaScript.

Both approaches initialize to an identical state (double nested arrays with each grid set to `0`).

However the first approach (`dp1`) later becomes an issue when referencing the indices for some reason. I'm assuming it has something to do with nesting the `new` keyword.

```js
const dp1 = new Array(6).fill(new Array(4).fill(0));

const dp2 = new Array(6);
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    dp2[i] = new Array(4).fill(0);
}

for (let i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
        dp1[i][j] = `${i}, ${j}`;
        dp2[i][j] = `${i}, ${j}`;
    }
}

console.log(dp1);
console.log(dp2);
```

`dp2` results in this (which is how it should be):

```js
(6) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
1: (4) ['1, 0', '1, 1', '1, 2', '1, 3']
2: (4) ['2, 0', '2, 1', '2, 2', '2, 3']
3: (4) ['3, 0', '3, 1', '3, 2', '3, 3']
4: (4) ['4, 0', '4, 1', '4, 2', '4, 3']
5: (4) ['5, 0', '5, 1', '5, 2', '5, 3']
```

But, `dp1` results in this:

```js
(6) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
1: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
2: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
3: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
4: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
5: (4) ['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dp1` is filled with the same array instance because there's only one constructor call. `dp2` is filled with distinct arrays.
So any time you change something in `dp1`, it's changed in all lines.
The last iteration sets the first row to `['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']` so all rows are set to `['0, 0', '0, 1', '0, 2', '0, 3']` in `dp1`.

Comment: Thanks. I had wrongly thought `.fill(val)` filled the array with new instances of `val` for each position. Instead, if `val` is an object, it stores the reference to the same object for every position.